# How to consolidate code into one file for same feature on all views using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was using 4 different views and four different controller for some thing similar in each $state , only data source `socket.io` is different so i tried to consiladated into one view and controller. but i am not getting `searchEnv` and states loaded. 
Any idea how can i fix this issue ?

app.js

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'web/global/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'view/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.dit', {
        url: '/:type',
        templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
        controller: 'DitCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.st', {
        url: '/:type',
        templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
        controller: 'DitCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.uat', {
        url: '/:type',
        templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
        controller: 'DitCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.prod', {
        url: '/:type',
        templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
        controller: 'DitCtrl',
    });
});
```

DitCtrl.js

```
var searchEnv = $stateParams.type;
$scope.event = [];
socket.on(searchEnv + 'Consumer', function(data) {
    var obj = {
        file: $scope.filename,
        data: data
    }
    var messageSize = getBytesForBuffer(data);
    $scope.event.push(data);
});
```

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.tabs = [{
        heading: 'Home',
        route: 'app.home',
        active: true
    },
    {
        heading: 'DIT',
        route: 'app.dt({type: '
        dt '})',
        active: false
    },
    {
        heading: 'ST',
        route: 'app.st({type:'
        st '})',
        active: false
    },
    {
        heading: 'UAT',
        route: 'app.uat',
        active: false
    },
    {
        heading: 'LSP',
        route: 'app.lsp',
        active: false
    }
];
```

Comment: but it make sense if i have a change i have to change code in four different html and js files.

Comment: can you make  a fiddle

Comment: sorry dont have access to fiddle

Comment: try merging app.dt and app.st to one and see

Comment: what you mean by merge ?

Comment: merge 2 states and routes and use state params

Comment: or do you think i can keep states and based on $stateParams use as searchEnv by keeping one view one controller for all the states, can you give me an example how i can merge states and one controller ?